# Need Help Performing Same Formula Across All Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would one go about performing the same formula across multiple sheets. More specifically I want to Sum everything in Column B in sheet2 and have the value output to A1 and then have everything sum in column B on sheet3 and output into A2 on sheet 1. Now I need to do this for 100s of sheets and was hoping there was a "grab and drag solution" such as the one when you are citing only from 1 sheet to autorecognize which sheets you are trying to cite as you drag/copy the formula to multiple cells.

Comment: Get a list of sheets in a helper column, then use SUM(INDIRECT()) to get the name of the sheet from the helper column.

Comment: i have =SUM(INDIRECT(M1)!A2:A1048576)  and getting a #REF error. M1 is the cell where the sheet name is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Scott's suggestion in the comments, if you have a column (say, `A`) containing the sheet names of the worksheets whose values in column `B` are to be summed, the following formula will obtain the desired result:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(A1 & "!B:B"))
```

[image: Worksheet]

The Excel `INDIRECT` function will return a range from a supplied string argument, therefore, this formula concatenates the string value found in cell `A1` (the worksheet name) with the literal string: `"!B:B"` to complete the range specification.

As shown in the image, this may then be dragged to automatically source the sheet name from subsequent rows, thus obtaining the sum from varying worksheets.

#### EDIT:

Following Scott's comment, should the worksheet names contains spaces, it may be necessary to surround the worksheet name with single quotes, i.e.:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!B:B"))
```

Comment: You may want to add the `'` in case the sheets have spaces in their names: `=SUM(INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!B:B"))`